# Ubuntu Server sendmail to google email with same domain

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

I am using ubuntu server version 11.01

and I use sendmail to deliver email.

I cannot received the email send from the server to Google services, which they are in the same domain name.

part of the sendmail log:
relay=mail.google.com, dsn=4.0.0, stat=Deferred: Connection timed out with mail.google.com

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, Gmail accepts mail on smtp.google.com:587. It seems you are using mail.google.com:25, try changing this configuration first.

If it still doesn't work, Google specific relay setup can be found at http://www.phinesolutions.com/sendmail-gmail-smtp-relay-howto.html

Good luck!

Comment: Content-Type: message/delivery-status

Reporting-MTA: dns; mydomain.com
Arrival-Date: Wed, 30 Nov 2011 11:01:18 +0800

Final-Recipient: RFC822; cs@mydomain.com
X-Actual-Recipient: RFC822; cs@mail.google.com
Action: failed
Status: 4.4.7
Remote-MTA: DNS; mail.google.com
Last-Attempt-Date: Mon, 5 Dec 2011 11:03:58 +0800